# Precision-Recall curve strange shape

Tags: machine-learning, roc, lightgbm, precision-recall

Anyone have similar Precision-Recall curve? Why my precision starts from 0?
This is LightGBM algorithm used on 3GB data, 55 million rows times 11 columns.

[image]

This is my results:

[image]

Comment: Why precision not starting from 0? If your threshold is `1`, then everything is classified as negative, both precision and recall will be zero. However, if your model is really good, then by lowering threshold a bit, say `0.99`, then you have a lot of True Positive. And you would see a jump in Precision.

Comment: In any case, this is not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be because of outliers in your dataset, especially because you have a class that is way more represented than the other.

Looking at your confusion matrix, I think that your algorithm predicted, with a very high confidence, a small amount of false positives.

This means that when the threshold is around 0.99999 (something very high), the first instances to be predicted as class 1 are actually from class 0, leading to a recall and a precision of 0. Then, as you lower the threshold, you start having a huge amount of true positives, creating the straight vertical line going near 1 precision.

This means that your curve is **totally normal** ! If you really wanted to get rid of this straight line, you would have to remove those false positive that have a high confidence.